# odoo multi select field .. create list values to choose from

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

im new on this field and i want to create  fixed list containing the days of week to choose from it in multiselect field ..i think i need use many2many relation .(the whole idea to choose vacation days for every person)
so how i pass this fixed list to  manytomany field for ex:

```
Holidays = [(saturday, saturday), (sunday,sunday), (monday, monday),(tuesday, tuesday), (wednesday', 'wednesday),(Thursday, Thursday),(Friday,Friday)]

     vacation = fields.Many2many('Holidays')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you would need a new model for weekdays & then you would apply vacation relation to the new weekdays.

```py
class CustomWeekdays(model.Models):
    _name = 'custom.weekdays'

    name = fields.Char()
    day_type = fields.Selection([
        ('saturday', 'Saturday'),
        ('sunday', 'Sunday'),
        ('monday', 'Monday'),
        ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
        ('thursday', 'Thursday'),
        ('friday', 'Friday')
    ])
    
    def name_get(self):
        ''' Here you should define how search the name '''
        pass

class CustomHoliday(model.Models):
    _name = 'custom.holiday'

    name = fields.Char()
    vaction_ids = fields.Many2many('custom.weekdays', string='Days')
```