# Create tag field with preselect options

Tags: tags, odoo-14

my goal is to create tag field on partner view with options that can be preselected - as for example on original tag field with multiple values that can be selected. Combination of selection field with many2many_tags widget.

This is my XML and I know its working because I tried with category_id field

```
<field name="category_id" widget="many2many_tags" string="ISO Country Code"/>
```

I'd like to replace category_id with my own list of values that can be selected from on frontend as when you use tags and can select predefined ones.

I tried using this solution [odoo multi select field .. create list values to choose from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544572/odoo-multi-select-field-create-list-values-to-choose-from) but when I copy this inside my .py file and try to call "vaction_ids" field there is error:

"Field "vaction_ids" does not exist in model "res.partner"

Help please, what do I need to do to predefine values and to call that field in XML?

Comment: Please add your code that's giving the error `"vaction_ids" does not exist ` I think you may not  have created this field, or possibly you have added this field in res.partner model and the module is not updated from the back-end [refer odoo mates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zXnlycSXog)

Comment: Sure, this is the code - I put it in models/models.py and inside __init__.py I added line from . import models

I'm sending you image because of comment line limitations https://ibb.co/JnpZ4Mp

Comment: search vaction_ids in your project folder you may have created this field in res.partner model or put it in res.partner view; the code in the picture looks okay

Comment: I changed it to completely new name 'my_custom_ids' and error is still the same - here are screenshots

Error: https://ibb.co/wZqDsW2
PyFile: https://ibb.co/Ctcd6vW

Comment: Yes you are adding the field in res.partner module error is not because of the code you shared but it's in the XML file in securikett module and res_partner_view.xml file

Comment: What is the error with XML file, I don't get it - field is being called like any other.

Comment: you made my_custom_id in `custom.holiday` but in XML you used it in partner form view